# How to retrieve the ou of the group a user belongs to in LDAP

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have a series of users and groups. Users' DNs can be added to the group's uniquemember attribute. How can I query LDAP such that I send a user dn and it returns to me the OU of the group that user belongs to?

I am doing this based on the LDAP at ldap.forumsys.com.

See the screenshot below:

[image: LDAP Tree]

Thanks.

Comment: What about filter `(uniquemember=YOUR_USER_DN)`?

Comment: It works for me... e.g. `(uniquemember=uid=einstein,dc=example,dc=com)`.

Comment: So it did, thanks. I was putting double quotes around the value for uniquemember. To me it looked weird having the value without them... Can you add your answer as a proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a pretty common equality match filter, for example:

```
(uniquemember=uid=einstein,dc=example,dc=com)
```

Note, that the value is not quoted. You only need to escape / replace special characters (e.g. parenthesis). More information about LDAP filter syntax can be found in [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515).

Also keep in mind that LDAP filters are very simple and provide only simple value matching (this can be confusing to people used to SQL and complex queries with joins, subselects, functions, etc.).